# want to send location to server continuously after 2 min

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use following code to get current location:

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)


#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
`#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}


#endif

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

NSLog(@"latitude: %f, longitude: %f",self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

it works fine, but i want send location to server continuously after 2 min.what i should do for that?

Comment: You either need to request always or when in use authorisation, not both. For your case you probably want always.  You need to implement the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method and then when you receive a location update check the timestamp.  If it is more than 2 minutes since you updated your server, update your server

Comment: i make that change in my code bro....

Comment: but how to do didUpdateLocations....please post your answer in detail...@Paulw11

Comment: I think it's not possible to update location continuously after 2 min, Apple doesn't support that. And if you add this to your project than most chances of rejecting an app by apple.

Comment: @Pramod.....Then what should i do ..?

Comment: Why you want to get the location details in every 2 mins?